# threejs on change texture IExplorer show black

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js, textures

my project work fine on chrome and firefox, but i have problem on Explorer...

I try to change the texture in the same way i do on chrome but the object become black and don't return any error... what i need to change?

the code i use

```
//create textureMaterial
function CreateTextureMaterial(ImageName){
    var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName); 
    var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map:Texture});
    return Material;
}
//!!
//change Texture
function ChangeTexture(ObjectName, TextureMaterial){
    obj = view3D.scene.getObjectByName(ObjectName);
    obj.material = TextureMaterial;
}
```

Comment: you probably need to create a fiddle to test it with.

Comment: i check better the function and the problem is caused from path...
i get the path from a background image that on IE work with url(".."), on chrome url(...)